# After a JQuery Ajax call, unable to remove "X-Requested-With" from subsequent Slim URL redirect request headers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, slim

After a JQuery AJAX call, all subsequent Slim redirects includes "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest" in the request header. As a result, content of the redirected page is being returned in the background in the response, but browser is not redirecting to the intended URL. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

My Ajax call is given below (this is an implementation of: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow):

```
function signInCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['code']) {
        // Hide the sign-in button now 
        $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');
        // Send the code to the server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../google/',
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(authResult['code']);
            },
            data: "gplustoken="+authResult['access_token'],
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
         });
    } else if (authResult['error']) {
         // There was an error.
    }
}
```

}

PHP Slim URL redirect code is given below:

`$app->redirect($app->urlFor("home"));`

For the context of above line, kindly see:
https://github.com/TheRosettaFoundation/SOLAS-Match/blob/master/ui/RouteHandlers/UserRouteHandler.class.php#L413

I tried to remove the 'X-Requested-With' from the request header in the PHP/Slim Code as below, but it did not work either.

```
 $isAjaxRequest = $app->request->headers->get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest';
 if ($isAjaxRequest) {
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']))
     {
         unset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);
         //$app->request->headers->set('X-Requested-With','');
         $app->redirect($app->urlFor("home"));
     }

  } else
       $app->redirect($app->urlFor("home"));
```

Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Slim docs for the [Http Headers](http://dev.slimframework.com/phpdocs/classes/Slim.Http.Headers.html) object, you should be able to achieve this by calling the remove method:

```
$app->request->headers->remove('X-Requested-With');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Tried this. But does not seem to work either :(